# Select rows based on textarea value

Tags: php, mysql, select, sql-like

Depending on the search pattern I need to get the data displayed from the server.

```
include("dbconfig.php");
$sql="select * from blog where title LIKE '{$title}%'";
$res=mysql_query($sql);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
    echo"<tr>";
        echo"<td><img src='uploads/".$row['file']."' height='150px' width='200px'</td>";
        echo"<td><h3>".$row['title']."</h3>".$row['description']."</td>";
    echo"</tr>";
}
```

Comment: <div class="col-sm-3">
  <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" placeholder="please enter your search">
  </div>

Comment: So? What is the issue you're facing?

Comment: what is an issue @swapnika ?

Comment: **Stop** using deprecated `mysql_*` API. use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`.

Comment: mysql_* is deprecated functionality in PHP 7..Try to use PDO or mysqli_*

Comment: I shortened the title, retabbed the code, and added a couple of tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a complete rewrite that implements mysqli as commented under the question.  For security & ease of use, it uses a [prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) with a [bound parameter](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) and [bound results](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php).

(Also notice, I've replaced the `*` wildcard in your SELECT. It is always good practice to only ask the database for exactly what you need.)

```
$db=new mysqli("localhost","username", "password","database");  // do this in your include
if($stmt=$db->prepare("SELECT `file`,`title`,`description` FROM `blog` WHERE `title` LIKE ?")){
    $search="{$_GET['title']}%";  // I assume this is passed with $_GET
    $stmt->bind_param("s",$search);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($file,$title,$description);
    while($stmt->fetch()){
        echo"<tr>";
            echo"<td><img src='uploads/{$file}' height='150px' width='200px'</td>";
            echo"<td><h3>{$title}</h3>{$description}</td>";
        echo"</tr>";
    }
    $stmt->close();
}
```

p.s. Typically table searches are done by using `%` on both sides of your `LIKE` value.  Your search will only return results that "start with `title`".  Please consider changing this in your code.

Answer (score -1):

Change the query like below:

```
$sql="select * from blog where title LIKE '".$title."%';
```

Comment: What are you expecting the `%` to do? did you mean to put i between the `"'`? (`...LIKE '".$title."%'`)